# get specific value from parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dataset, report, builder

I have a multi-valued parameter TimeMonthOfYear(from cube) that contains January Februrary...December.
I want to set a default value showing current month using MonthName(Month(Today)) (I tried it and it didn't work) when running report...

If I do this [Time].[Month Of Year].&[October] it works! October is selected in dropdown after previous dropdown (Year) was selected.

I don't want to do it the "hard coded" way...I have tried 
[Time].[Month Of Year].&[MonthName(Month(Today))] and 
="[Time].[Month Of Year].&["&MonthName(Month(Today))&"]" without luck

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you just missing parentheses after today? `MonthName(Month(Today()))`

Comment: I've already tried that, thx though. Problem still exists

Comment: How are you populating the parameter exactly, because default value of `=MonthName(Month(Today()))` works fine if I set up available values manually with values of the full text names.  (Even with multi-select enabled.)  If there is whitespace being passed in that may be messing up the exact match...

Comment: is the year included in the parameter value? in that case you would probably have to append the year to =Month... with a similar expression for year.

Comment: My parameter comes from a dimension called Time that has Month Of Year which consists of a list with months, January-December. I also have Year as another parameter. My parameter TimeMonthOfYear has some constrains

... , [Measures].[ParameterLevel]} ON COLUMNS , [Time].[Month Of Year].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@TimeYear, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DimOrganisationDealerName, CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ...so I can't hard code the values in available values since it accepts only \[Time\].\[Month Of Year\].&\[September\] format

Comment: How about `="[Time].[Month Of Year].&[" + MonthName(Month(Today())) + "]"`

Comment: `[Time].[Month Of Year].&[September]` is the text your stored procedure needs, or the report to display the default value? I think I confused myself here :)

Comment: I think I know why it's not working. If I do (MonthName(Month(Today)) in a textbox with report language en-GB it gives me October. But if do it in parameter default value expression it gives me Oktober. My computers regional settings is Swedish. The question now is how do I convert a parameter expression to use English language.

Comment: Try:
1. Open rdl and click outside the report body
2. Click F4 to open properties window
3. Select Report from first dropdown in properties window
4. Localization --> language --> =User!Language

Comment: Did you see Heidi's response? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3f553058-ca07-44c2-9187-b873acde54d4/specify-default-month-value?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Yup :)

Well it's now working with may be a not so nice solution but will work for now with the help of vb code.

in standard value I have ="[Time].[Month Of Year].&[" + Code.SetMonth() + "]" and custom code 

Function SetMonth() As String

Dim x as STRING

x =CStr(MonthName(Month(Today))) 'CStr not needed I think

If x = "januari" Then
 x = "January"
ElseIf x = "februari" Then
 x = "February"
...

End If

Return(x)

End Function

That is giving me the current month after selecting value in year drop-down :)

Comment: That's a decent workaround, put it into an answer and accept it so the question doesn't float around please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup :) Well it's now working with may be a not so nice solution but will work for now with the help of vb code. in standard value I have ="[Time].[Month Of Year].&[" + Code.SetMonth() + "]" and custom code Function SetMonth() As String Dim x as STRING x =CStr(MonthName(Month(Today))) 'CStr not needed I think If x = "januari" Then x = "January" ElseIf x = "februari" Then x = "February" ... End If Return(x) End Function That is giving me the current month after selecting value in year drop-down :)